# What is contaminating this switch statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library, aspose

I have a system which is doing following,

- Upload documents to SharePoint
- Event receiver will add job to DB, Create a folder for job in Document Conversion Directory
- A directory watcher will trigger Document Conversion windows service
- Windows service will get batch of 10 jobs from DB (using main thread)
- On start Windows service creates X number of threads based on processor's cores (using Parallel For)
- Then creates worker thread with timeouts for every db jobs (this is different from parallel For threads)
- and it carries on...
- Oh while converting... in worker threads.. we are calling ActiveDirectory, logging to DB (Read, Write) and uploading document back to SharePoint

I manage to break it... if I upload a password protected document... and soon after upload a powerpoint document, powerpoint document throws password incorrect exception etc..

but if there's gap inbetween both documents even 60 seconds, it all works fine which means powerpoint document does converts to PDF.

Following is the code but I had to trim unnecessary parts out of it,

Here is the main class where things start from,

```
 Parallel.For(0, noOfThreadsToRunOnPDFServer, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = noOfThreadsToRunOnPDFServer },
    i =>
    {
        this.docConvService.ProcessDocuments(i);
    });
```

Then the conversion is happening here...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace PDFService
{
    public class AsposePDFConverter : IPDFConverter
    {
        private IDocConversionSettings settings;
        private ExceptionDispatchInfo conversionException = null;
        public enum SupportedExtensions
        {
            Doc,
            Docx,
            Xls,
            Xlsx,
            Pdf,
            Pps,
            Ppsx,
            Ppt,
            Pptx,
            Txt,
            Html,
            Mhtml,
            Xhtml,
            Msg,
            Eml,
            Emlx,
            One,
            Vsd,
            Vsdx,
            Vss,
            Vssx
        }

        public AsposePDFConverter(IDocConversionSettings settings)
        {
            this.settings = settings;
        }

        private void SyncThreadStartWithTimeout(ThreadStart threadStart, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(threadStart);
            workerThread.Start();

            bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeout);
            if (!finished)
            {
                workerThread.Abort();
                throw new ConversionTimeoutException("PDF Conversion exceeded timeout value");
            }
        }

        public MemoryStream ConvertToPDF(string documentName, Stream docContent, double timeoutMS)
        {
            this.conversionException = null;

            MemoryStream outStream = null;
            MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream();
            docContent.CopyTo(inStream);
            inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            SupportedExtensions documentExtension;
            string szExtension = Path.GetExtension(documentName).TrimStart('.');
            if (Enum.TryParse(szExtension, true, out documentExtension))
            {
                switch (documentExtension)
                {
                    case SupportedExtensions.Doc:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Docx:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Txt:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Html:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Mhtml:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Xhtml:
                        SyncThreadStartWithTimeout(
                                () => { outStream = ConvertWordsToPDF(inStream); },
                                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMS));
                        break;
                    case SupportedExtensions.Pps:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Ppsx:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Ppt:
                    case SupportedExtensions.Pptx:
                        SyncThreadStartWithTimeout(
                                () => { outStream = ConvertSlidesToPDF(inStream); },
                                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMS));
                        break;
                }

                // Conversion happens on sub-threads so they can time out, if they throw an exception, throw it from this thread
                if (this.conversionException != null)
                    this.conversionException.Throw();

                return outStream;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatNotSupportedException("Document type is not supported");
            }
        }

        private MemoryStream ConvertWordsToPDF(Stream docContent)
        {
            try
            {
                Aspose.Words.License lic = new Aspose.Words.License();
                lic.SetLicense(this.settings.AsposeLicensePath);
                Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(docContent);

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                doc.Save(stream, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);
                return stream;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.conversionException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private MemoryStream ConvertSlidesToPDF(Stream docContent)
        {
            try
            { 
                Aspose.Slides.License lic = new Aspose.Slides.License();
                lic.SetLicense(this.settings.AsposeLicensePath);
                using (Aspose.Slides.Presentation presentation = new Aspose.Slides.Presentation(docContent))
                {
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    presentation.Save(stream, Aspose.Slides.Export.SaveFormat.Pdf);
                    return stream;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.conversionException = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error is,

> Error during Document PDF Conversion.   Details are: PDFConversionID:
>   6061,     DocumentName: powerpoint.ppsx, WebURL: REMOVED, UploadedBy:
>   REMOVED, ConversionDuration: 00:01:06.3072410
>
> Aspose.Words.IncorrectPasswordException: The document password is
>   incorrect.    at Aspose.Words.Document. (Stream  , LoadOptions  )
>   at Aspose.Words.Document. (Stream  , LoadOptions  )    at
>   DocumentPDFConversionService.AsposePDFConverter.ConvertWordsToPDF(Stream
>   docContent) in...

As you can see there is something very fishy going on

Comment: If you change your Parallel.For loop to a standard For loop does the problem still exist? This will help you diagnose if there's a thread safety issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same instance of this.docConvService in multiple threads, so your conversionException property is probably written by the password-protected doc while your other document is processing. You should instanciate a new instance of your AsposePDFConverter, or change the way you return exceptions, e.g. in a result-object returned by ConvertToPDF, that contains a MemoryStream and your error.

Seperate instance for each request :

```
Parallel.For(0, noOfThreadsToRunOnPDFServer, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = noOfThreadsToRunOnPDFServer },
    i =>
    {
        new AsposePdfConverter(settings).ProcessDocuments(i);
    });
```

Returning a result-object :

```
 public ConversionResult ConvertToPDF(string documentName, Stream docContent, double timeoutMS)
{
    /** Your code **/
    return new ConversionResult() 
        {
        MemoryStream = memoryStream,
        ConversionException = conversionException
        };
}

class ConversionResult {
    MemoryStream MemoryStream {get;set;}
    ExceptionDispatchInfo ConversionException {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, In addition to this I am thinking about moving document conversion to completely different service, atm our windows service is converting document, reading and writing to database and SharePoint and calling active directory + logging to file system. While you looked at it would you suggest any architecture for document conversion only :)

Comment: @Mathematics Aspose.Words API does support multi-threading and the only thing, you need to take care of is, only one thread should access Document Object in one time. For example, you may write a method in which a new instance of the Document is initialized and output is being saved in a global List object, which can be accessed after the end of execution, to get all output streams/files. You may implement your multi-threaded routine as per your requirements of tasks, by following above guidelines. I work as support developer at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli I am able to fix the issues by given guideline but can we have a quick chat please I would like to discuss couple of things shouldn't take too much time :)

Comment: @Mathematics you may surely ask anytime and I believe that you have also posted similar inquiry over Aspose Forums. Though you may ask here but at the forums, I believe we can reply you with more details and useful information accordingly. :)

Comment: Please join this room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150080/aspose